Conduktor not executing
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-120gb-intel-blr1-01:~# Conduktor

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

How do I execute Conduktor and get rid of this error?
